Tailwind css pt-12 class not working on a divcss
I can't figure out why the tailwind class pt-12 isn't showing up when I look at the page in a browser.
https://pastebin.com/uaQ7SUxZ
On line 12 of the pastebin link, I have the pt-12 there.
I built and compiled the latest tailwind css classes, and verified I see .pt-12 in my style.css
specific line:
<div class="overflow-x-auto pt-12">

Yet when I load up the page in the browser, there is no visible padding-top at all.
The weird thing is, if I change pt-12 to just p-12, it works!!
Can anyone see what I am missing?
Thanks!

It works perfectly fine https://play.tailwindcss.com/z2hEPvDeA5

Huh, I understand it looks right in that link, but when I am using Chrome, it doesn't look like that at all in my browser.

I'm using Chrome also, and it looks fine. Maybe if you share a working example, we could help you

It's also working haha. Do you have any extensions active? Try opening it from incognito maybe

@Ba2sik - ughhhh, Incognito worked.  What the hell.  I don't know if my browser is caching the css somehow, or cloudflare tunnels is doing it.  I've been forcing hard refresh on the browser too and it still didn't update.  Thanks for helping me identify that its a local issue for me!!

You're welcome :)

Thanks to some help from Ron Zano, this issue is a local issue to my computer.

Do you have any extensions active? Try opening it from incognito maybe.

